# Bad performance on scroll view loaded with 3 view controllers, drawn with CALayer

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, calayer

i have a scroll view loaded with 3 view controllers. each view controller is drawing its layers with that code -
(there us more then that but I pulled it out to check if it will help). still i have very crappy sliding.
 any help ?

shani

```
CALayer *sublayer = [CALayer layer];
sublayer.backgroundColor = [Helper cardBackGroundColor:card].CGColor;
sublayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);
sublayer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
sublayer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
sublayer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
sublayer.frame = CGRectInset(self.view.layer.frame, 20, 20);
sublayer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
sublayer.borderWidth = 2.0;
sublayer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:sublayer];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing things with `CALayer` often yields poor performance. We usually use a stretchable image to get adequate performance. When you think of it, it does make sense to render it before hand rather than using the iPhone's limited processing power to render it in real time.

It's possible that you can get adequate performance from `CALayer`, but drawing a png will probably still be faster, thus saving battery life time.

**EDIT:** So here's an example to explain the concept.

This code actually replaced a CALayer drawing that was too slow.

```
UIImageView *shadow = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
shadow.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"shadow.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:16.0 topCapHeight:16.0];
[contentView addSubview:shadow];
[shadow release];
```

`shadow.png` is 34 by 34 pixels and contains a shadowed square. Thanks to the stretchable image it's possible to resize the square without stretching the shadow. For more information about this I would suggest reading the documentation for `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:`. Also Google will help you find guides on how to work with stretchable images. If you have more questions I'll be happy to answer them.

Comment: Hi. Can you explain more about the stretchable technic you are describing?

Answer (score 1):

You have a mask (assuming you somewhere say masksToBounds=YES) and a shadow on this layer. Both cause an off screen rendering pass.

Please watch the WWDC 2010 Session 425 - Core Animation in Practice Part 2

Which you can find here;

http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/

Comment: Hi, thanks. it was indeed the shadows and the reference was great. i received the above answer as it was the first one.